# Crear Controllers con metodos HTTP en .NET

Tags: .net

Genere los modelos de mi sistema a partir de la base de datos. Luego estoy agregando los controladores haciendo click en Agregar nuevo elemento con scaffolding. Pero el caso es que aparece asi por ejemplo:

```
namespace APIGESTION.Controllers
{
   public class CajafuertesController : Controller
   {
       private readonly gestionContext _context;

       public CajafuertesController(gestionContext context)
       {
           _context = context;
       }

       // GET: Cajafuertes
       public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
       {
           return View(await _context.Cajafuertes.ToListAsync());
       }

       // GET: Cajafuertes/Details/5
       public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
       {
           if (id == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           var cajafuerte = await _context.Cajafuertes
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Idcajafuerte == id);
           if (cajafuerte == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           return View(cajafuerte);
       }
```

Es decir a ese codigo le falta por ejemplo:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

Ademas de los metodos Get, put etc antes de cada metodo de la clase controller.

Como podria corregir eso? Otra cosa que no entiendo es porque Visual Studio cambia los nombres de las entidades, por ejemplo tengo "Categoria" de productos, pero el archivo de modelo se creo como Categorium.cs al igual que luego el controlador: Categoriumscontroller.cs. alguien sabe porque pasa eso?

Answer (score 0):

Pues realmente lo único que te falta, es agregar el código que dices, este se agrega entes de la declaración del método, aquí te pongo dos ejemplos que te pueden ayudar

```
[Route("Details]")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> get_Details(int? id)
       {
           if (id == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           var cajafuerte = await _context.Cajafuertes
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Idcajafuerte == id);
           if (cajafuerte == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           return View(cajafuerte);
       }

//Ojo que los nombres de los métodos deben de ser diferentes
[Route("Details]")]
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> put_Details(int? id)
       {
           if (id == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           var cajafuerte = await _context.Cajafuertes
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Idcajafuerte == id);
           if (cajafuerte == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           return View(cajafuerte);
       }
```

Para las rutas, este lo puedes agregar directamente al inicio de tu controlador para que todos los métodos dentro usen la misma ruta, y solo vayan cambiando dependiendo de que ruta le pongas a cada método.
Para este ejemplo la ruta "default" de todos los métodos, va a ser `api/CajafuertesController`

```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   public class CajafuertesController : Controller
   {
   //Métodos
   }
```

Con los nombres, asegurate de que lo escribes bien, no creo que VS te cambie los nombres solo porque si, igual, al renombrar VS te dice que si cambia el nombre en todas las referencias, puedes decirle que si y haga el cambio, comprueba de igual manera que lo haya echo bien
Espero te funcione